# Get List of Open Generic Types .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

how does one resolve multiple registrations of implementations. I want to get a list of implementors:

Registration:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IClient<>), typeof(Client1));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IClient<>), typeof(Client2));
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
public class ClientFactory : IClientFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ClientFactory(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IClient<ListingBase> GetClient(string clientName)
    {
        var clients = _serviceProvider.GetServices<IClient<ListingBase>>(); // listing base is abstracct class

        // match by name - filter by name
        // do stuff here

        return (IClient<ListingBase>)clients.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Getting:

> Exception while executing function: Importer. System.Linq.Expressions:
> An expression of type 'Client1' cannot be used to initialize an array
> of type 'IClient`1[....Abstract.ListingBase]

It does work when I only register one instance and do `.GetService<IClient<ListingBase>>()`

However I want to get a List of all implementors.

EDIT:
Adding more code for clarity:

```
public interface IClient<TModel> : IClient where TModel : ListingBase
{
    public Task<TModel> MapToObject(Stream file);
}

public interface IClient { }



public abstract class ClientBase<TModel> : IClient<TModel> where TModel : ListingBase
{
    // .. other common stuff
    
    public abstract Task<TModel> MapToObject(Stream file);
}
```

Implementations:

```
public class Client1 : ClientBase<Model1> // Model1 inherits from ListingBase
    {
{

    public override Task<Model1> MapToObject(Stream file) // Model1 inherits from ListingBase
    {
        // do mapping from Json / Stream to object


        return Task.FromResult(new Model1());
    }
}

// Another client

public class Client2 : ClientBase<Model2> // Model2 inherits from ListingBase
    {
{

    public override Task<Model2> MapToObject(Stream file) // Model2 inherits from ListingBase
    {
        // do mapping from Json / Stream to object


        return Task.FromResult(new Model2());
    }
}
```

Changed it to this:

```
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IClient), typeof(SaborClient));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IClient), typeof(FlexClient));
```

...

```
public IClient<ListingBase> GetClient(string clientName)
{
    
    var clients = _serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IClient));
    // match by name

    var t = clients.FirstOrDefault();
    return (IClient<ListingBase>) t; // failing here
}
```

now I do get a list of clients, BUT, cast is failing. Please help

Comment: Don't you want something like `services.AddScoped(typeof(IClient<TypeParameter>), typeof(Client1));`?

Comment: or `services.AddScoped<IClient<TypeParameter>, Client1>();`

Comment: i want to be able to pull out IClient dynamically from the list (by some name or something similar)